# How to merge single level df to a multilevel df in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have a multilevel df 'AB'

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [5, 1, 4]],
             columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = pd.DataFrame([[3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]],
             columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], A.columns])
B.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], B.columns])
AB = pd.concat([A, B], axis = 1)
```

And I have a single level df 'C', that has a different index than 'AB'

```
C = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], columns=['AA', 'BB'], index=[1, 2, 3])
```

I need to merge 'C' to the 'B' level of df 'AB'. The result should keep the multilevel like this:

```
    A           B
    A   B   C   A   B   C   AA   BB
1   1   5   2   3   3   3   1    1
2   2   4   4   2   2   2   1    1
3   3   3   1   4   4   4   1    1
4   4   2   2   5   5   5
5   5   1   4   6   6   6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `MultiIndex` on `C` with the first level of being `'B'`, and then use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
C.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], C.columns])
ABC = AB.join(C, how='left')
```

The resulting output:

```
   A        B                
   A  B  C  A  B  C   AA   BB
1  1  5  2  3  3  3  1.0  1.0
2  2  4  4  2  2  2  1.0  1.0
3  3  3  1  4  4  4  1.0  1.0
4  4  2  2  5  5  5  NaN  NaN
5  5  1  4  6  6  6  NaN  NaN
```